# how do i delete border line of a pictures on my game?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

As shown in the photo, there is a small line on the right side of the pin. 
I would like to get rid of this?

I have seen this in other game as well.
Not all pictures are like this, but the majority of them are.

I used zwoptex to merge all pictures and call them out separately.

[image: the green pin has this problem whereas the yellow one doesnt]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html search for generate mipmaps, turn it off

Answer (score 0):

[![You need to cut the extra image in unity follow the step given below][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYUg9.png**strong text**